# AppleScript : Time format change + Calendar events

Tags: date, calendar, applescript

I'm trying to create a script to log my current time and my finish time
do a specific action them sent an email with this same time variable and create a calendar event with this time variable :

```
set FinsihDate to (current date) + 10 * hours + 30 * minutes
set startingDate to (current date)


set plistR to {FinsihDate:FinsihDate, starteddate:current date}

tell application "System Events"
    set plistf to make new property list file ¬
        with properties {name:"~/Desktop/MY_Time.plist"}

    set plistf's value to plistR
end tell



## Email
property lastWindowID : missing value
tell application "Mail"
    set windowIDs to id of windows
    if windowIDs does not contain lastWindowID then
        set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"Started early", content:"Hi ..., \n \nI started early today : " & (current date) & ", I will leave at " & FinsihDate & "\n \nKind Regards,\nKevin " & return & return}
        tell newMessage
            set visible to true
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {name:"Name", address:"@apple.com"}
        end tell
        activate
        set lastWindowID to id of window 1
    else
        tell window id lastWindowID
            set visible to false
            set visible to true
        end tell
        activate
    end if
end tell



set startDate to date (current date)
set endDate to date FinsihDate

tell application "Calendar"
    tell (first calendar whose name is "calendar")
        make new event at end of events with properties {summary:"Work", start date:startDate, end date:endDate, description:"ITS Fraud Prevention", location:"Apple"}
    end tell
end tell
```

1. Time format

   the time format on the email is " Monday 4 June 2018 at 14:25:57," when I just want 14:25

I tried this :

```
set myTime to (time string of (current date)) + 10 * hours + 30 * minutes
```

> Result: error "Can’t make \"14:27:02\" into type number." number -1700
>   from "14:27:02" to number

2. Calendar

When creating the Calendar event I have this error

> error "Can’t get date (date \"Monday 4 June 2018 at 14:29:34\")."
>   number -1728 from date (date "Monday 4 June 2018 at 14:29:34")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for itemising the individual errors that you encountered and want fixing.  This made is so much easier for me to read this question and decide it was one I wanted to answer, because I don't actually have to test your script at all as I can immediately see what the problems are:

① Your parentheses are in the wrong place.  Change this:

```
set myTime to (time string of (current date)) + 10 * hours + 30 * minutes
```

to this:

```
set myTime to time string of ((current date) + 10 * hours + 30 * minutes)
```

② The error indicates that you've tried to take a variable of type `date` and then declare it again as type `date`.  AppleScript doesn't like this.

Change these two lines:

```
set startDate to date (current date)
set endDate to date FinsihDate
```

to this:

```
set startDate to (current date)
set endDate to FinsihDate
```

I haven't tested the rest of the script.

P.S. You misspelled your variable name `FinsihDate` (which I *assume* is meant to be `FinishDate`).  However, it's misspelled consistently throughout the script, so it doesn't make any practical difference.